# Returning function-local variable as reference

Tags: c++, static, reference

I found this source code:

```
inline GUID& WString2Guid(wstring src)
{
    static GUID result;
    HRESULT hr = ::CLSIDFromString(W2OLE(const_cast<WCHAR*>(src.c_str())), &result);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        //ERROR: The string '%s' is not formatted as a GUID!
        throw(E_INVALIDARG);
    }
    return result;
}
```

What's the use of returning a reference here? The calling code cannot get a reference anyway because the variable would have left its scope by then. So does this little `&` sign make any difference?

To clarify/extend the question: In the same example program, the function is called as

```
GUID guid = WString2Guid(id); // way 1
```

If I wanted to make use of the reference, wouldn't I have to call

```
GUID& guid = WString2Guid(id); // way 2
```

instead?

And another question; why is the `CLSIDFromString` function called with the `::` scope operator before? This would only make any sense if there was another local function declared with the same name, wouldn't it?

Comment: See here for details on `Static (C++)` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. `result` is a `static` local variable, so it will exist even after the function exit. Don't confuse this with non-static local variable.

`::` in `::CLSIDFromString` tells the compiler to choose `CLSIDFromString` from the global namespace, in case if there are many definition of `CLSIDFromString`  defined in other namespace(s), visible at the call-site.

Comment: Comment only - The implementation is not thread safe, it must use TLS.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is static, so it will stay alive. But it's stupid code anyway, it should just return the GUID by value. The scope operator is probably a personal preference of style.

Comment: The scope operator is often used to indicate that you really intend to call a Windows API function directly and not a framework wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The key bit is the `static` keyword.  It binds `result` to the function itself, not a particular function call.  It lives on after a particular call returns, so it's safe to return by reference.

The scope resolution operator (`::`) by itself like that makes a call to `CLSIDFromString` in the global namespace.  Perhaps the code author had another version of that function in his own namespace somewhere.  The compiler will tell you if a call to a function is ambiguous and thus you would need to add it.  Even if the call *isn't* ambiguous, it doesn't hurt anything by being there.

Answer (score 0):

to your first question - the local variable is declared as static which means its memory buffer is preserved from one function call to another.